# user define function call at the time of set_time_limit PHP

Tags: php, function, user-defined-functions, termination

I want to run a file for a fix period of time. I can use set_time_limit function for this. But I want to call a function at the time of termination. This function is necessary to be called. Otherwise I will not be able to run this file again.

Is there any way to call a function at the time of termination when set_time_limit limitation meets.?

Comment: Are you using this script for web request or running from command-line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to set a callback function when the script execution is complete or `exit` function is called.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `register_shutdown_function`:

```
<?php
function shutdown() {
    // 3 seconds are over
    set_time_limit(0); // now we want no limit anymore
    echo "Shutdown!\n";
    while(true); // some other long action
}
error_reporting(0);
set_time_limit(3);
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
while(true); // some long action
```

The `error_reporting` call is done to avoid an error message when the time limit exceeds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have a doubt, as you mentioned in your code, set_time_limit with parameter value 3 that means file will execute for 3 mins and at the time of termination register_shutdown_function will be called. But what makes it possible to run callback function now because time limitation is applied. What if callback function will run a long action script.

Comment: @AbhimanyuSharma That's a good point. I've tested this and it seems that as soon as the callback function is called, the PHP interpreter starts the timeout again, so the shutdown function runs for at most 3 seconds, too. You can prevent this by calling `set_time_limit(0)` in the shutdown function, which sets an infinite time limit. I've added this to my answer. But notice that it is generally not a good idea to do long actions on shutdown, because the callback is also run when the script stops for another reason other than that the timeout exceeded!